# binary search left and right index to find median of two sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, median, divide-and-conquer

Two sorted arrays `A` and `B` are given having size `l` and `m` respectively. Our task is to find the median of these two sorted arrays combined. Suppose the length of the combined array is `n` i.e. `n = l + m`.By definition the median will be greater than half of the  elements  and less than the other half.

Suppose `A[i]` is the median. Then since A is sorted so

```
                            A[i] >= A[k] for all k = 0 to i - 1
```

and it will also be greater than **`j = ⌈n/2⌉- (i - 1)`** elements in `B` as `i + j` must be  equal to `⌈n/2⌉`.

```
                      A[i] >= B[k] for all k = 0 to ⌈n/2⌉- (i - 1)
```

If `A[i]` is not the median, then depending on whether `A[i]` is greater
or less than `B[j]` and `B[j + 1]`, you know that `A[i]` is either greater than or less than the median.

Thus binary search for A[i] can be done here. Following is the pseudo code I have found from a [website](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/f1fea97937edc97ae96691b80651421a_ps9sol.pdf):

```
                MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1 . . l], B[1 . . m], left,right)

                 if left > right:
                   MEDIAN-SEARCH(B, A, max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − l), min(m, ⌈n/2⌉))

                 i = ⌊(left + right)/2⌋

                 j = ⌈n/2⌉ - i

                 if (j = 0 or A[i] > B[j]) and (j = m or A[i] <= B[j + 1])
                   return A[i]

                 else if (j = 0 or A[i] > B[j]) and j != m and A[i] > B[j + 1]
                   return MEDIAN-SEARCH(A, B, left, i − 1)

                 else
                   return MEDIAN-SEARCH(A, B, i + 1, right)
```

The initial call to find median will be

```
                 MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1..l], B[1..m], max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − m), min(l, ⌈n/2⌉))
```

My question here is:

1. I am not able to visualize intuitively how **`left`** and **`right`** initial values are being used in the code above.
2. What will be time complexity of the algorithm? Will it be `O(log(N))`? or will it be `O(log(max(l, m)))`?

Comment: Point 1 is not a question. What do you ask here? Point 2: O(log) = O(log(max(, )).

Comment: Point 1 is a question. I can verify the correctness of left and right values by taking few examples. But how the initial values of left and right are determined, that is I am not able to visaulize.

Comment: You are stating that you cannot visualise it. That is not a question, that is an assertion. Note that if your question would be "how to visualise this?", then that is too broad. In that case show your visualisation efforts and where you get stuck. For instance, start by drawing adjacent boxes for each array element, and use arrows or coloring to indicate where an index is pointing to. Repeat during the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Lets take an example. `A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], l = 11` and `B = [2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 14], m = 6`. Initial values of `left` and `right` will be `left = max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − m) = max(1, 9 - 6) = 3` and `right = min(l, ⌈n/2⌉) = min(11, 9) = 9`. Thus `left` and `right` initial values are `3` and `9`. And if we reverse the array i.e. take `A` as `B` and `B` as `A`, then `left = 1` and `right = 6` for current array `A`. How left and right are initially determined? How to prove that median will be within `left` and `right`?

Answer (score -1):

If your task is to find the median, you could merge the arrays, which you already did, sort the entire thing, and then find the middle term using the following code:

```
//pretend your combined array in arrCombined
if (arrCombined.size() % 2 == 1) {
    cout << arrCombined[arrCombined.size()/2];
}
else {
    cout << (arrCombined[arrCombined.size()/2] + arrCombined[arrCombined.size()/2 - 1])/2;
}
```

As for your question, if you cannot understand point 1, really it's that the left and right are integers saving the left and right extents of what you are searching, meaning the left is the leftmost possible value based on your elimination, and right is the rightmost possible value. As for your second question, as [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) already said in the comments, O(log) = O(log(max(, )), so you might need to rephrase what you need.

Comment: Initial values of left and right are `max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − m), min(l, ⌈n/2⌉)`. How these are arrived I am not able to visualize.

Comment: merging the two arrays increases the time-complexity to O(l+m) from logarthmic complexity

Comment: You do not have to sort the whole thing. Use merge sort to combine the two arrays until you reach position (l + m)/2 in the combined array. There is no need for any further merging once you have found the median position.

Comment: @rossum That is true, though it should just save us around n/2 comparisons, depending on the initial order of the elements.